# Is there a way to specify the output dimension of pytorch least square solution?

Tags: python, pytorch, linear-algebra, tensor

With `3 by n by k` tensor `A` and `1 by k by m` tensor `x` we can have`Ax = B` where `B` has shape of `[3, n, m]`

`torch.linalg.lstsq(A, B)` returns a `3 x k x m`tensor as solution. Is there a way to find the `1 by k by m` tensor `x`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between `torch.lingalg.lstsq` and `torch.matmul` is that `torch.lingalg.lstsq` computes its answer based on batch-wise operation while `torch.matmul` does not.
And your `1 by k by m` solution will be non-batch wise solution or some kind of global solution that can commonly be applied across whole batch. This case, you can simply reduce the batch dimension and obtain your least square solution.

```
A_re = A.reshape(1,-1, k)
B_re = B.reshape(1, -1, m) # or torch.matmul(A_re, x)
x = torch.linalg.lstsq(A_re, B_re)
x.size()
> torch.Size([1, k, m])
```